# Restore MySQL database to production

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

I have a website that used to 'restore' a mysql database to production... Basically I create a backup .sql file and then restore that to the prod environment. This worked fine when the database was small. Now that the database is several 100MB, the restore is slow (predominantly due to internet upload, but I imagine also due to restoring at the server). The problem with a slow restore is that my users sit idle as this process occurs, which is acceptable for a second or two, but not to the 60+ seconds that I currently face.

What is the proper way to restore an entire database as it gets big?

Comment: I recommend to ask this at Database Administrators site https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since you've tagged this with `amazon-web-services`, can we assume that your database is running in RDS? If yes, have you considered using an RDS snapshot?